# Как работают замыкания в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-faq

Как сказал Альберт Эйнштейн:

Если вы не можете объяснить что-то шестилетнему, то вряд ли вы сами вполне понимаете.

Я тут попытался объяснить замыкания знакомому 27-ми лет, и он ничего не понял.

Как бы объяснить замыкания тому, кто знаком со всеми принципами программирования, необходимыми для понимания замыканий (функциями, переменными, областью видимости и т.д.), кроме, собственно, замыканий?

Этот вопрос переведён с англоязычного SO.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/

Comment: Вот здесь есть подборка статей и видео про замыкания в js https://inforso.ru/main?page=0&pageSize=15&selectedTopicId=43&selectionId=1

Answer (score 50):

Это перевод из [community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111200/1968972).

В JavaScript функции могут быть описаны не только одна за другой, но и одна внутри другой. Когда у вас одна функция находится внутри другой, то внутренняя функция имеет доступ к переменным внешней функции.

```js
function внешняя(x) {
  var tmp = 3;

  function внутренняя(y) {
    alert(x + y + (++tmp)); // выведет 16
  }
  внутренняя(10);
}
внешняя(2);
```

Этот код всегда выдаёт 16, потому что функция `внутренняя` видит `x`, который является переменной в функции `внешняя`. В данном случае аргументом функции. Так же `внутренняя()` может видеть `tmp` из `внешней()`.

Это и называется замыкание или closure. Если точнее, замыканием называется именно внешняя функция, а всё что внутри неё называется closure environment или среда замыкания.

Иногда говорят, что замыкание это функция которая возвращает функцию, это неправильно. Для того, чтобы назвать функцию замыканием, достаточно того, чтобы внутренняя функция обращалась к переменной извне своей области видимости.

```js
function foo(x) {
  var tmp = 3;

  return function (y) {
    alert(x + y + (++tmp)); // will also alert 16
  }
}

var bar = foo(2); // bar is now a closure.
bar(10);
```

Приведённая выше функция также выдаст 16, поскольку `bar` даже после завершения `foo` продолжает иметь доступ к `x` и `tmp`, пусть даже сама переменная `bar` и не находится внутри области видимости в которой они были объявлены.

При этом, поскольку переменная `tmp` всё ещё находится внутри замыкания `bar`, она продолжает увеличиваться при каждом вызове `bar`.

Вот простейший пример замыкания:

```
var a = 10;
function test() {
  console.log(a); // вывод 10
  console.log(b); // вывод 6
}
var b = 6;
test();
```

При запуске функции в JavaScript, для неё создаётся окружение, то есть список всех видимых ей переменных, не только аргументов и переменных объявленных внутри неё, но и снаружи, в данном примере это 'a' и 'b'.

Можно создать более чем одно замыкание в одном окружении, вернув их массивом, объектом или привязав к глобальным переменным. В таком случае, все они будут работать с **тем же самым** значением `x` или `tmp`, не создавая отдельных копий.

Поскольку в нашем примере `x` это число, то его значение **копируется** в `foo` как его аргумент `x`.

С другой стороны, в JavaScript всегда используются ссылки, когда передаются объекты. Если бы вы вызвали `foo` с объектом в качестве аргумента, то возвращённое замыкание вернуло бы ссылку на оригинальный объект!

```js
function foo(x) {
  var tmp = 3;

  return function (y) {
    alert(x + y + tmp);
    x.memb = x.memb ? x.memb + 1 : 1;
    alert(x.memb);
  }
}

var age = new Number(2);
var bar = foo(age); // bar теперь замыкание ссылающееся на age.
bar(10);
```

Как и следовало ожидать, каждый вызов `bar(10)` увеличивает `x.memb`. Чего вы могли не ожидать, так это, что `x` продолжает ссылаться на тот же самый объект, что и `age`! После двух вызовов `bar`, `age.memb` будет равен 2! Кстати, так и происходят утечки памяти в HTML объектах.

Answer (score 21):

Замыкание - способность функции запомнить контекст, в котором она была определена, и обращаться к нему в процессе вызова. Под контекстом здесь понимаем переменные, которые доступны в месте её определения - функция неявно сохраняет ссылки на них и может потом к ним обращаться - даже после того, как исполнение программы вышло за рамки области их видимости. Переменные в этом случае не собираются сборщиком мусора, а благодаря этим неявным ссылкам продолжают жить, пока жива функция и, соответственно, могут использоваться функцией.

Comment: _"способность функции запомнить контекст"_ -- если из функции вызывается document.body, то можно сказать, что функция запомнила document.body?

Comment: document.body - это не переменная, а свойство объекта, на который мы ссылаемся при помощи глобальной переменной document. То, что я писал, не относится к свойствам, а относится лишь к самим переменным. Наверное можно сказать, что мы захватили глобальную переменную document, но, т.к. она глобальная, нет нужды её захватывать - она итак доступна отовсюду (кроме мест, где её видимость перекроют локальной переменной с тем же именем - а в этом случае мы к ней и не смогли бы обратиться, забрав в замыкание). Так что замкнём мы её или нет - разницы не будет на практике никакой, мы это даже не проверим.

Answer (score 11):

Это хороший вопрос!
Долго я сам не втыкал что к чему, хотя активно их использовал.
Со временем дошло (искренне на это надеюсь).
Но в двух словах тоже не раскажешь, [вот](http://javascript.ru/basic/closure) хорошее описание их работы.
Итак:
Замыкания - это дальний родич инкапсуляции, наверное.
В JS область видимости создают только функции. Поэтому при создании любой функции у неё два особых свойства (их, конечно, больше, но мы их не рассматриваем): `[[scope]]` (там хранятся все созданные в ней сущности — переменные, агрументы, функции и пр., никак не доступна программисту) и `__proto__` (ссылка на сущность, в которой создана функция, никак не должна быть доступна, можно влиять только через `prototype`, но некоторые браузеры успешно на это забивали).
Например, при запросе в функции переменной интерпретатор ищет её в соответствующем `[[scope]]`, если не находит, то переходит по ссылке в `__proto__` и обыскивает его скоуп. Не находит - опять переход и обыск. И только когда убеждается, что дошёл до конца (главный объект, `window` у браузеров), выдаёт окончательную ошибку что не нашёл переменную.
Т.к. внешнее окружение не имеет доступа до внутренних `[[scope]]` (оно о них даже не знает), то внешне невозможно добраться до внутренних переменных, когда внутренние легко добираются до внешних.

Если в двух словах и грубовато, то как-то так.

Answer (score 9):

Замыкание - это доступность переменных (области видимости) для текущей функции из вышестоящей функции, в которой она была объявлена

Answer (score 4):

```
function mCounter(){
    var count = 0;
    function counter(){ // создаем функцию и увеличиваем переменную
        count = count + 1 ; // можно +=
        return count;
    }
    return counter; // возрашаем функцию которая использует
 свободную переменную. Это замыкание.
}
var dCount = mCounter();//здесь привызове mCounter() мы получаем замыкание(функцию с окружением)
console.log(dCount());//1  при вызове dCount()
//  значение count берется из переменной count,
// которая находится в окружении замыкания.
console.log(dCount());//2
console.log(dCount());//3
console.log(dCount());//4
//мы вызываем функцию которая создает
// др.функцию и возвращает ее вместе с окружением,
// в нашем случае содержащим свободную переменную count.
// Это и есть замыкание.
//свободная переменная count не связана ни с какими значениями
(потому и наз.свободная)
//т.е. count объявляется за пределами функции counter()
//в окружении, где наша свободная переменная , функция 
становится замкнутой, а
//если взять функцию с ее окружением, получится замыкание.
```

Answer (score 1):

объяснить на примере.

```
function func1() {
     var a = Math.random();
     return function () {
            return a;
     }
}

var f = func1();
console.log(f());
var f2 = func1();
console.log(f2());

0.34218455478549004
0.6286177076399326
```

Answer (score 0):

Интересный пример замыканий, любят спрашивать на собеседованиях, может кому пригодится:

```js
function sum(a) {
  const add = function(b) {
    if (b !== undefined) {
      a = a + b;
      return add;
    }
    return a;
  }
  return add;
}

console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)(4)()) //10
```

В данном случае замыкается переменная `a` внутри анонимной функции в переменной `add`

Comment: > Интересный пример замыканий, любят спрашивать на собеседованиях, может кому пригодится... А в чём тут проявляется замыкание?
Т. к. b не определено (т. е. b == indefined), внутренняя функция [не отрабатывая условие] возвращает просто то значение аргумента (a), которое приняла внешняя функция. Значит add будет равен a, и его возвращает внешняя функция.
В итоге просто возвращается изначально переданное значение аргумента. Только я не понял почему все эти значения - 1, 2, 3, 4 - складываются. Где тут операция сложения?

Comment: @Norik_A, замыкается параметр `a` в `sum(a)` в который и происходит накапливание результата `a = a + b;`

Comment: @Norik_A Внутри анонимной функции в переменной add есть операция сложения. Для понимания данного кода, можно запустить его с дебагером и пройтись по шагам. А замыкается здесь переменная a из функции sum в анонимной функции в переменной add