# Ссылка на объект js

Tags: javascript

```
function _Class(){
 this.test_obj = {
   init: function(){
    document.onmousedown = this._mousedown;
   },
   _mousedown: funtion(){
    //!!! Как отсюда правильно обратиться к объекту test_obj?
  }
 }
}

var Init = new _Class();
Init.test_obj.init();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стандартный для таких случаев трюк - запомнить this в [замыкании](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/414092/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-javascript):

```js
function _Class(){
 const _this = this;
 this.test_obj = {
   init: function(){
     document.onmousedown = this._mousedown;
   },
   _mousedown: function(){
     console.log(_this.test_obj);
     //!!! Как отсюда правильно обратиться к объекту test_obj?
   }
 }
}

var Init = new _Class();
Init.test_obj.init();
Init.test_obj._mousedown();
```

Еще как варинат, воспользоваться [bind](https://learn.javascript.ru/bind):

```js
function _Class(){
 this.test_obj = {
   init(){
     document.onmousedown = this._mousedown.bind(this);
   },
   _mousedown(){
     //!!! Как отсюда правильно обратиться к объекту test_obj?
     console.log(this);
   }
 }
}

var Init = new _Class();
Init.test_obj.init();
```

Еще один вариант, как избавиться от потери this - обернуть вызов метода в стрелочную функцию:

```js
function _Class(){
 this.test_obj = {
   init(){
     document.onmousedown = () => {
       this._mousedown()
     };
   },
   _mousedown(){
     //!!! Как отсюда правильно обратиться к объекту test_obj?
     console.log(this);
   }
 }
}

var Init = new _Class();
Init.test_obj.init();
```