# Как работают счетчики?

Tags: javascript

При объяснении как работает [[Scope]] зачачстую встречается такой пример:

```
function makeCounter() {
      var currentCount = 1;

      return function() {
        return currentCount++;
      };
    }

    var counter = makeCounter();

    alert( counter() ); // 1
    alert( counter() ); // 2
    alert( counter() );
```

Почему такой счетчик работает - для меня совершенно непонятно.

Каким образом число сохраняеется если каждый раз функция присваевает переменной еденицу?

Comment: Функция `makeCounter` вызывается и присваивает переменной единицу только один раз.

Comment: Почему? Как тогда вызывается функция внутри нее?

Comment: @brachkoff Вот так: `counter()`

Comment: `counter()` вызывает `makeCounter()` которая сработала один раз и внутри которой лежит анонимная функция которая срабатывает несколько раз. Почему она срабатывает несколько раз если единственный способ ее вызвать это вызвать `makeCounter`?

Comment: counter **не** вызывает makeCounter. counter и есть та анонимная функция

Comment: На самом деле, этот вопрос это точный дубликат, и его необходимо закрыть.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы было легче понять пример, рекомендую отвлечься от замыканий:

```js
var currentCount = 1;

var counter = function() {
  return currentCount++;
};

console.log(counter(), counter(), counter());
```

Пример из вопроса отличается только тем, что этот код завёрнут в функцию, которая позволяет иметь несколько счётчиков со своими внутренними переменными в каждой.

```js
function getCounter() {
  // тот же код
  var currentCount = 1;

  var counter = function() {
    return currentCount++;
  };

  // вернём counter
  return counter;
}


var c1 = getCounter(); // вызываем всего 1 раз, значит и единицу присвоим один раз
// в переменной c1 в данный момент функция из локальной переменной counter
console.log('c1 =', c1);

// и мы можем вызывать её, как и в примере без функции выше
console.log('c1()', c1(), c1());

// Также, всегда можно получить новый счётчик:
var c2 = getCounter();
console.log('c2()', c2(), c2(), c2());
```

Comment: Ну и конечно же тем, что переменная в вопросе не валяет в глобале xDD

Comment: Для этого можно всё это в IIFE завернуть, но будет отвлекать от сути.

Answer (score 1):

Такой подход называется замыканием. Дело в том, что когда функция `makeCounter()` вызывается, то поднимается скоуп, в котором создается переменная. Переменная в свою очередь используется в анонимной функции, которую возвращает текущая функция `makeCounter` и при удалении скоупа эта переменная не может быть удалена т.к. она используется в анонимной функции. Поэтому эта переменная "висит" в памяти и к ней обращается анонимная функция, сохраняя значения между контекстами.

Это вкратце. Вроде ничего не напутал. Более подробно можно почитать например тут – https://learn.javascript.ru/functions-closures

P.S. `makeCounter()` не вызывает анонимную функцию, а **возвращает** ее и она у вас находится в переменной `counter`, которую вы вызываете как функцию.

P.P.S. На эту тему есть кстати много ответов уже, и вот один из них. Спасибо `@MedvedevDev` – [Как работают замыкания в JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/414092/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-javascript)

P.P.P.S Как работают функциональные выражения можно почитать например тут – https://learn.javascript.ru/function-declaration-expression

Comment: Этот пример оттуда

Comment: И что вызывает counter()?

Comment: Анонимную функцию, которую вернула функция `makeCounter()`

Comment: Почему только ее?

Comment: @brachkoff потому что только она лежит в переменной, которую вы вызываете как функцию. Добавил в ответ. Можно почитать тут https://learn.javascript.ru/function-declaration-expression