# Переменные, объявленные в модуле, которые затем используются в обработчике событий, сохраняются внутри обработчика?

Tags: javascript

```js
(function(){
  var input = document.querySelector("input");
  var count = document.querySelector(".count");
  
  input.addEventListener("change", function(){
    count.textContent = input.value.length;
  });
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text">
  <span class="count">0</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Смысл этого кода — отображать в `<span>` кол-во символов, которые введены в `<input>`.
Проблема в том, что я не понимаю, почему обработчик события `function(){count.textContent = input.value.length;})` знает про переменную `count`, ведь `count` — переменная созданная в модуле, в экранированной функции, и после выполнения JS она "удаляется" из области видимости. А когда происходит событие `change`, `count` уже нет. Как это работает??? Неужели обработчик сохраняет для себя переменные, которые будет использовать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/414092/Как-работают-замыкания-в-javascript вам нужно почитать про замыкания