# В чем преимущества замыкания в примере?

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Задача привязать контекст к определенной функции

Решение с замыканием:

```
const Person = {
 name: "Jhon",
 job:"programmist",
}

function logPerson () {
console.log(`Person: ${this.name}, ${this.job}`)
}

function bind(context, fn){
return function () {
fn.apply(context);
}

}

var bind =  bind(Person, logPerson);
bind();
console.log(bind);
```

Решение без замыкания:

```
const Person = {
 name: "Jhon",
 job:"programmist",
}

function logPerson () {
console.log(`Person: ${this.name}, ${this.job}`)
}

function bind(context, fn){
return fn.apply(context);


}

bind(Person, logPerson);
```

Не могу понять в чем преимущество первого решение с замыканием. В том, что функцию в переменную можно положить?

P.S. буду благодарен если объясните какие впринципе есть преимущества использования замыканий. Есть пример с счетчиком, где замыкание происходит на переменной

```
function makeCounter() {
  var currentCount = 1;

  return function() { 
    return currentCount++;
  };
}

var counter = makeCounter(); 


alert( counter() ); // 1
alert( counter() ); // 2
alert( counter() ); // 3
```

Но тут как бы понятно, что преимущество в том, что эту переменную никак нельзя изменить вне функции. В чем еще преимущества использования замыканий?

Comment: первые два блока кода нельзя сравнивать, потому что они делают разные вещь, а для PS есть отдельный вопрос:  [Как работают замыкания в JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/414092/186999)

Comment: в решении "без замыкания" - **не решается** задача привязать контекст к функции.

Comment: @Grundy можете пояснить на счет второго примера?

Comment: @Grundy почему во втором примере не решается задача привязки контекста к функции

Comment: Потому что там функция сразу выполняется в нужном контексте.

Comment: @Grundy, заранее извиняюсь за скорее всего тупые вопросы, но все же. 1 и 2 пример отличаются только тем, что во втором примере fn.apply(context) была не сразу вызвана, а сначала помещена в переменную bind. Под этим подразумевается "привязка"?

Comment: А что ты подразумеваешь под словами "привязать контекст"?

Comment: @Grundy передачу контексту определенной функции?

Comment: Но привязать и передать это разные вещи. Во втором случае вы выполняете функцию один раз с нужным контекстом. В первом случае вы получаете функцию со связанным контекстом, которую вы можете вызывать сколько угодно раз с этим контекстом. Если вам нужно однократное выполнение, второго варианта достаточно. Если вы эту функцию с этим контекстом захотите вызывать много раз из разных мест, тогда нужен первый вариант.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, не только из разных мест, но и с разными параметрами

Comment: Да. То есть разница между первым и вторым вариантами — приблизительно как разница между однократно использованным фрагментом кода и этим фрагментом, заключённым в функцию для регулярного использования с параметрами.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty "Если вы эту функцию с этим контекстом захотите вызывать много раз из разных мест, тогда нужен первый вариант." - Но ведь я также могу просто использовать эту конструкцию bind(Person, logPerson) сколько угодно раз в любом месте. Или это не так?

Comment: Ну, если вам удобнее в каждом месте громоздить эти вызовы и вы уверены, что у вас везде будут доступны переменные с этим контекстом, то можно и так. Это всё равно что вместо вызова функции каждый раз использовать её содержимое. Иногда так и делают, если функция небольшая и хотят сэкономить на накладных расходах вызова.

Comment: Или представьте вариант, что вам нужно из модуля экспортировать функцию, привязанную к контексту, но вы не хотите открывать этот контекст наружу, не хотите экспортировать его. Тогда вам не обойтись без первого варианта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В приведенном примере разницы нет, так как функции выполняются сразу же в месте объявления, следовательно в момент вызова функции ей доступны все переменные, что и в момент создания.

Разница появляется, как только место объявления и вызова разносятся.

Преимущество замыканий в том, что в момент выполнения функция может обращаться к переменным, которые доступны в момент создания, но могут быть недоступны в месте вызова.

Пример демонстрируется в коде `PS` c функцией `counter`: В месте создания ей доступна переменная `currentCount`, в месте вызова - уже недоступна.