# Если функция суммы используется без аргументов, то возвращать значение суммы всех переданных до этого значений. JS

Tags: javascript

Мне нужна помощь, друзья!
У меня написана функция суммы, которая принимает числа в качестве аргументов и возвращает их сумму.

```js
const sum = (...arr) => {
    return arr.reduce((a, b) => {
        return a + (+b || 0);
    }, 0);
};


console.log(sum(1, 2, 3, -4, 6, 5)); // 13
console.log(sum()); // 0
```

Как сделать, если функция используется без аргументов, то возвращать значение суммы всех переданных до этого значений?

Comment: это на самом деле как-то не логично. Зачем такое делать? Сумматор должен суммировать и всё. Если ему ничего не дали и суммировать нечего, пусть вернёт какое-нибудь "ничего",  или в крайнем случае 0.

Comment: Вам нужно изменить подход, потому что так сделать, как Вы хотите - никак нельзя. 
Например вы можете сохранять сумму в отдельную переменную const mySum = sum(1, 2, 3, -4, 6, 5); И в дальнейшем использовать эту переменную, если у вас будут отсутствовать аргументы.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Из вашего вопроса не совсем понятно чего вы хотите, я написал два варианта, но не уверен, что именно вы подразумевали.

### Вариант 1

```js
let prevSum = 0;
const sum = (...arr) => {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return prevSum;
  }

  const currentSum = arr.reduce((a, b) => {
    return a + (+b || 0);
  }, 0);

  prevSum = currentSum;

  return currentSum;
};


console.log(sum(2, 2)); // 4
console.log(sum(1, 2, 3, -4, 6, 5)); // 13
console.log(sum()); // 13
```

В этом варианте, если аргументы не были переданы, возвращается последняя сумма которая была возвращена.

### Вариант 2

```js
let totalSum = 0;
const sum = (...arr) => {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return totalSum;
  }

  const currentSum = arr.reduce((a, b) => {
    return a + (+b || 0);
  }, 0);

  totalSum += currentSum;

  return currentSum;
};


console.log(sum(2, 2)); // 4
console.log(sum(1, 2, 3, -4, 6, 5)); // 13
console.log(sum()); // 17
```

В этом варианте, если аргументы не были переданы, возвращается общая сумма которая получается в результате сложения переданных до этого чисел.

---

Но как отметил [@SpaceResearcher](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/441356/space-researcher), функция, которая суммирует, должна только суммировать и не более того, так что не рекомендую вам делать что-то подобное.

Вот более правильный подход (Я использовал [замыкание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/414092/)):

```js
const sum = (...arr) => {
  return arr.reduce((a, b) => {
    return a + (+b || 0);
  }, 0);
};

const mySum = createSum();

console.log(mySum(2, 2)); // 4
console.log(mySum(1, 2, 3, -4, 6, 5)); // 13
console.log(mySum()); // 17

function createSum() {
  let total = 0;
  const summ = (...arr) => {
    if (arr.length === 0) {
      return total;
    }

    const currentSum = sum(...arr);

    total += currentSum;

    return currentSum;
  }

  return summ;
}
```

Comment: Второй вариант, это то что я искал! Спасибо!

Comment: @GregoryEA 1. Отметьте вопрос галочкой, так вы укажите что вы нашли правильное решение на ваш вопрос. (Галочка слева от ответа) 2. Ознакомьтесь с третьим блоком кода, там я сделал более правильное решение с точки зрения программирования.

Comment: Почему бы не перенести проверку `arr.length === 0` в самое начало функции? Зачем лишний раз пытаться дернуть `reduce`?

Comment: @OliverPatterson логично, сейчас же перенесу.